# (near "null": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO null

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to save data into a database, but it seems that the onCreate method is not run. Might be this might be another problem but the logcat

```
12-01 01:22:41.785 19724-19724/com.example.user.timetable_test E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "null": syntax error
12-01 01:22:41.795 19724-19724/com.example.user.timetable_test E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting _length=1 _name=Break
                                                                                 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "null": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO null(_length,_name) VALUES (?,?)
                                                                                 #################################################################
                                                                                 Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
                                                                                 Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
                                                                                    (near "null": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO null(_length,_name) VALUES (?,?))
                                                                                 #################################################################
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1058)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:623)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1607)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1479)
                                                                                     at com.example.user.timetable_test.setup.TableDBHandler.addEntry(TableDBHandler.java:79)
                                                                                     at com.example.user.timetable_test.setup.SetTable$PlaceholderFragment$1.onClick(SetTable.java:227)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
                                                                                     at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10826)
                                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

The SQLite class is:

```
package com.example.user.timetable_test.setup;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import com.example.user.timetable_test.MiscData;


public class TableDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private MiscData data = MiscData.getInstance();

    private static int      DATABASE_VERSION   = 1;
    private static String   DATABASE_NAME      = "Timetable.db";
    private static String[] TABLE_DAY          = new String[MiscData.getInstance().getDays()];
    private static String   COLUMN_SESSION_NUM = "_id";
    private static String   COLUMN_NAME        = "_name";
    private static String   COLUMN_LENGTH      = "_length";
    private SQLiteDatabase db;


    public TableDBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory,
                          int version){

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);

        db = getWritableDatabase();
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase){


        Log.i("SQL", "DB Created");
        for(int i = 0; i < data.getDays(); i++){

            TABLE_DAY[i] = data.getDay(i + data.getFirstDay());

        }

        for(int i = 0; i < data.getDays(); i++){
            String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_DAY[i] + "(" + COLUMN_SESSION_NUM +
                           " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ," + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT," +
                           COLUMN_LENGTH + " INTEGER " + ");";

            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(query);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1){

        Log.i("SQL", "DB updated");


        for(int j = 0; j < data.getDays(); j++){
            TABLE_DAY[j] = data.getDay(j + data.getFirstDay());
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE EXISTS " + TABLE_DAY[j]);
        }
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);


    }


    public void addEntry(int day, String name, int length){

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME, name);
        values.put(COLUMN_LENGTH, length);

        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(TABLE_DAY[day], null, values);
        db.close();

    }
}
```

I am using an array to create a dynamic number of tables.

The log message in the onCreate method doesn't show up in the logcat, I checked  a lot.

Calling the addEntry method:

```
tableDBHandler.addEntry(page, sessionSpinners[i].getSelectedItem().toString(), Integer.parseInt(lengthText[i].getText().toString()));
```

If I changed the `DATABASE_VERSION` from 1 the `onUpgrade` method is called, but if the version was 1 I cannot see the message from `onCreat`,  in the logcat.

Shouldn't this class create a .db file? Because after clicking the button, and running the method, I can't see any files in the app's folder.

Comment: I bet something that you create `tableDBHandler` with `tableDBHandler = new TableDBHandler(...);`.

Comment: @Tom already did so, the app is not crashing, but I a getting this error in the logcat

Comment: And is this the correct way to create that instance? Who calls `onCreate`?

Comment: @Tom I don't know, buy it seems that it is not called in the first place, the `Log.i("SQL", "DB Created");` line doesn't seem to run

Comment: So you know what to do: research how to properly create an instance of your `SQLiteOpenHelper` (to make sure that you're doing it correctly) and research *when* `onCreate` and `onUpdate` are called.

Comment: Check your query: INSERT INTO null(_length,_name) VALUES (?,?)

Comment: `INSERT INTO null(_length,_name) VALUES (?,?)` **NULL** is not a valid table name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`INSERT INTO null` - the table name is null. It comes from the `TABLE_DAY` array you initialize in your SQLite helper `onCreate()`. But [`onCreate()` is only invoked when the database file is created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run), not each time you open your database.

You could move the `TABLE_DAY` init from `onCreate()` to e.g. constructor.

> I am using an array to create a dynamic number of tables.

If the `TABLE_DAY` array is really dynamic, you're in much more trouble. Consider redesigning your database schema so that the tables are static but the content can be dynamic.

Comment: tbh, I think a "dynamic number of tables" is more concerning than a dynamic array. Tables == static, their data, less so.

Comment: The number of tables is on